Flooding and Patch below the bathroom
There was flooding in bathroom because a tap was accidentally open. Water came out on carpet
from the bathroom. Removed the water and made the surrounding dry in and around bathroom. But it resulted in a patch on the floor below. Not sure how long the patch will stay. Moved in a month ago and there seems to be no leakage in bathroom. Looks like the grout between tiles allowed the water to percolate.
How do I get rid of the patch? I am thinking the patch will dry in few days. Do I have to paint the whole ceiling or a patch is enough. One of the layers may come off also.

Update
That area is dry now. Hoping the water between the bathroom to the ceiling is dried now. Not sure what material the layers is between and if at all there is any permanent damage in the layers.

It depends on the amount of water, but a few weeks is a better guess than days.  If the ceiling is soft(push a finger in), the section will need replacement.

Obviously water staining on the ceiling under the bath. Let the area dry well for a week or so.
You then need to seal the stained area with a sealer/ primer. Then paint.
If you have the same paint that was on the ceiling, great!  If not you will need to try to match to your satisfaction, or paint the entire ceiling.

Thank you. By Seal you mean scratch few mm of  layer and then apply sealer/primer ?

No, I never mentioned scratching anything. Apply the sealer directly to the ceiling.  If the  paint is sagging, then that has to be removed, but you didn't mention anything sagging in your question.
